# Useless use of private variable in void context Perl

Tags: perl

I am getting the error

```
Useless use of private variable in void context
```

and it is at the line that contains a `}` only. However, I'm assuming it refers to the line before, which is `$final_value -= 4;`. I enabled diagnostics to get more info and it returned saying `You did something without a side effect in a context that does nothing with the return value`
But, if I remove the line `$final_value -= 4;`, the error stops coming, but my program doesn't work anymore. Can I just ignore this and continue ?

Thanks.

Edit- here's a part of the code

```
elsif($size_of_array == 2){
        if($array[0] > $array[1] && $array[0] >= 4){
            my $final_value = $array[0];
            for($final_value; $final_value > 0;){
                $line =~ s/(.*?)$/"$1\n" . ( q{ } x $final_value . "}")/e;
                $final_value -= 4;          
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry about that. The code is pretty long so I'm not sure how much of it I should've added. I've edited it now with the chunk that's causing the problem.

Comment: I strongly assume the errors comes from the `for($final_value; ...` part. Maybe you want to use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: @amon Yes you're right. I changed it to a while loop and it's working now. Thanks a lot. Perhaps it was because I didn't add the third part (the iteration?)?

Comment: The errors definitely come from the `for($final_value` loop

Comment: @amon you were first, write an answer?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - if `$final_value` were undefined, you'd get a different error: `Use of uninitialized value $final_value in numeric gt (>)`.

Comment: @Sobrique true.. I answered that comment before the post was edited, though you're correct. and comment removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The  syntax is wrong on your 'for' loop.

Perl expects C style, which means the first 'statement' should initialize, the second test, and the third increment.

Your 'initialize' isn't doing anything: you're just using the variable in a void context - which is what it's warning you about:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $final_value = 10;

for ( $final_value; $final_value > 0; ) {
   $final_value -= 1;
}
```

If you initialize `$final_value` or just leave it blank, it doesn't give you the same error.

```
for ( ; $final_value > 0; ) {
```

At this point, you might as well use a while loop.

Alternatively, you can go in the other direction:

```
for ( my $final_value = 10; $final_value > 0; $final_value -= 1) {
    print $final_value - 1;
}
```

or

```
for ( my $final_value = 10; $final_value--; ) {
    print $final_value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down and explaining it.